# Does Single Sign On (SSO) Integration possible in 12.5?

Tags: powerbuilder

We have an application in powerbuilder 12.5.Client asked to integrate SSO(Single Sign On) with the application.I couldn't get much help from sites.Is it possible in powerbuilder 12.5?Does anyoine know how can integrate it?

Comment: The documentation for your SSO framework will help you. Which SSO framework are you using?

Comment: We are using OAuth 2.0 framework for single sign on.

Comment: Never used it, but...

PowerBuilder 2017 R3 has OAuth 2.0 support

https://www.appeon.com/support/documents/appeon_online_help/pb2017r3/whats_new/ch01s09.html